# Why do people can downvote a question without justification?

Tags: discussion

I have a huge problem with my pc [Cannot restore Windows 8 from Windows 10 because of local administrator account](https://superuser.com/questions/965045/cannot-restore-windows-8-from-windows-10-because-of-local-administrator-account)

I am desperate and asking for help. To my surprise someone downvoted my question without justification.

I thank this anonymous guy for his lack of empathy !

Comment: Being sarcastic isn't helping your case.  I suspect you linked your local account to your Microsoft account, when that happens, a new account is created.

Answer (score -1):

Some people just do, it happens to everyone.  Just live with it !!